# CoreData seems to save wrong variable

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, swift3

I am trying to debug the below code.

1) CellClass has IBAction to change Bool value, the value declared as value: Bool

```
@IBAction func dashBrnPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
  value == true ? (value = false) : (value = true)
  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .reload, object: nil)
                                      // reloads the TableView
 }
```

2) I use UITableView controller with dequeueReusableCell and fetching CoreData. There is these lines only responcible for cell. "switchAction" is a value from CoreData

```
 if cell.value == true{
     switchAction.isOn = true

  }else{
     switchAction.isOn = false

  }

  DataBaseController.saveContext()
  cell.value = switchAction.isOn

  return cell
```

3) it seems to be working unless I restart the app. No crashes but it returns FALSE for value by default. I need store the value **back** to CoreData depending on what statement the button is.

The code is simplified of course.

Comment: Try renaming your attribute.  I've seen previous questions/answers which suggest that CoreData struggles with boolean attribute names beginning "is....".

Comment: it still returns FALSE after rebooting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is still unknowm but this code works

1) `cell.value` now is optional and equals `nil` while restarting the app

2) This code in cellForRow now firstly assigns optional value and only if the value exist stores the new value 
3) function willDisplay doesnt return UITableViewCell and not required

```
 switch cell.value {  
    case nil:

        if switchAction.dashboard == true{
            cell.dashBtn.tintColor = .white
            cell.value = true

        } else {

            cell.dashBtn.tintColor = myColors.opaceGrayColor
            cell.value = false
        }

    case true?:

    switchAction.dashboard = true
    cell.dashBtn.tintColor = .white
    DataBaseController.saveContext()


    case false?:

    switchAction.dashboard = false
    cell.dashBtn.tintColor = myColors.opaceGrayColor
    DataBaseController.saveContext()
}
```

I am happy and thank you for help! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I see the problem. In the block of code under part 2, here's what you're doing:

1. Set `switchAction.isOn` to the value of `cell.value`
2. Save `switchAction.isOn` to CoreData
3. Set `cell.value` to the value of `switchAction.isOn`

When you restart your app, `cell.value` defaults to false, and then you overwrite that false onto `switchAction.isOn` and save it back to CoreData. So even though `switchAction.isOn` might be loading with the correct value, you're overwriting it before you ever see it.

What you need is an assignment that goes the other way:

```
cell.value = switchAction.isOn
```

Since `cell` is a reusable table view cell, you can put that line in your `tableView(UITableView, willDisplay: UITableViewCell, forRowAt: IndexPath)` delegate function, which is called right before the cell is displayed.

Comment: Yes it would be the easiest way ..the issue is that the cell is dequeueReusableCell and it is not accessible from anywhere beside the cellForRow function :(

Comment: And you are right the value stored in core data even after restart is proper.  It overrides somewhere and this is awful 

Comment: @DanilMihnevich Sorry I missed the part about dequeueReusableCell. You can put that line in your `tableView(UITableView, willDisplay: UITableViewCell, forRowAt: IndexPath)` delegate function. Updated answer to add that.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean to put into the function just kind of cell.value = true/false? Or something more specific?

Comment: I mean put `willDisplay.value = switchAction.isOn` into your `tableView(:willDisplay:forRowAt)` function. That will transfer the value of `switchAction.isOn` to the cell's `value`, which I think is what you're trying to do.

Comment: It returns FALSE value by defoult anyway . Giving up for coding.   The strangest is that after rebooting I see correct value in second table (read only). It mens somwhere asserts FALSE after restart app...